# Sidebar on the hompepage only now moved to the bottom instead of being on the right. How do I move it back?

Tags: blogger, sidebar

So I have a free blogger theme for my blog, and I just noticed that when I go to the homepage my whole sidebar is now moved to the bottom?? On my posts and even when I click the second page to view older posts it's back to the right.

For example this is my homepage vs. page 2 of my posts

https://innerbeautybelle.blogspot.com/ vs. https://innerbeautybelle.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2017-10-07T13%3A16%3A00-05%3A00&max-results=7#PageNo=2

As you can see they change positions and I'm not sure if it's something in my coding or something on my default homepage that's making it change locations. I should mention I tried to go back and redownload the theme, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Help please?!

Comment: There is an interference with the layout elements. add your template code.

Comment: @Bassam my code is too long - is there a portion I can search in my code to paste? I have the most basic coding knowledge, so this code was a free template.

Comment: You can use pastebin.com or paste content of  `<div class="row" id="content-wrapper">`